# Как сделать сглаживание шрифта?

Tags: css, вёрстка

В Гугле нашел свойство -webkit-font-smoothing, которое работает пока лишь в Сафари и Хроме(у меня оно вообще не работает). Также видел, что можно добавить тень к тексту и предлагали следующий код:

```css
p{
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), /* наверх и влево */
     1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), /* вниз и вправо */
     1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* тёмная тень */
}
```

Вариант с тенью более-менее подходит, но нет ли других способов?

Answer (score 3):

Непонятно, в чём именно у вас проблема. Было бы хорошо увидеть пример вашего кода. Объясню основные свойства для оптимизации рендеринга шрифтов и для чего они нужны:

- `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` – свойство нужно для сглаживания кастомных шрифтов в Safari/Chrome для macOS/iOS.
- `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale` – свойство нужно для сглаживания кастомных шрифтов в браузере Firefox для macOS/iOS.
- `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` – обеспечивает качественные кернинг (интервалы между буквами) и лигатуры (соединение букв) во всех современных браузерах, кроме IE. Очень сильно тормозит рендеринг страницы в целом, поэтому рекомендуется использовать точечно, к примеру, на заголовках.

Кастомные шрифты в современных ОС и браузерах на дисплее с высоким разрешением по-умолчанию выглядят отлично и не требуют дополнительных оптимизаций. Применив `text-shadow` для «сглаживания» шрифта вы лишь его «размылите».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема возникает при больших размерах текста, пиксельные лесенки выглядят как-то не очень и хочется это убрать.

Comment: @RomanIceman, попробуйте применить свойство text-rendering: optimizeLegibility на блоки, с большим размером шрифта. Хотя я склонен к мнению, что вы видите лесенки из-за того, что у вас монитор с низким разрешением.

Comment: @RomanIceman, ещё нашел такое решение – использовать .svg-формат шрифтов, который по умолчанию сглаживается на Windows, в отличии от EOT, WOFF или TTF:

https://medium.com/@MateMarschalko/improving-font-rendering-with-css-3383fc358cbc

Comment: Да, возможно проблема в разрешении(1360×700 с чем-то, ноут), потому что на телефоне текст на сайте(любом) красивый, а  на ноуте пиксельные буковки(но с маленькими шрифтами не так заметно). Попробую недавно сверстанный сайтик на телефоне открыть

Comment: Да и на телефоне разрешение 1920x1080 при намного меньших размерах

Answer (score 0):

Да особо-то методов и не было, css не может влиять на рендер шрифтов в браузере, можно только делать легкое размытие, но смотрится все равно не так как хотелось бы. Еще нужно сказать что на отображение шрифтов влияют такие факторы как: экран, OS.

UPD:
можно попробовать свойство `text-rendering`, работает вроде как везде кроме IE